# How to stop head rotation tracking in Google VR SDK v1.5 in unity 5.6?

Tags: google-vr-sdk

SDK v0.8 had trackRotation variable in gvrHead Script. Making that false would do the  job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't a direct interface either, but you can get it by  `InputTracking.Recenter()`

trackRotation variable is useful in Unity without Google VR inside, such as Unity 5.6 before.